# How to retrieve data from mysql database in reverse order using JPA and store in a List?

Tags: java, mysql, list, for-loop, jpa

I use following method to retrieve data from mysql database and return as a List.

```
public List<Notification> getByUser(ApplicationUser applicationUser){
    List<Notification> notificationList = repository.findByUserId(applicationUser.getId());
    return notificationList;
}
```

I want to store these data in reverse order in the list, since I need retrieve new data at first. Is it possible to do? I'm retrieving data using Thymeleaf each method. I found that it is not possible to get data in reverse order using thymeleaf so I have to try it in the other way. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can't you sort it in reverse ?

Comment: yes. I did it in database level. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implements `Comparable` in `Notification` class and override `compareTo()` method to reverse element on specific field.

Then,

```
List<Notification> notificationList = repository.findByUserId(applicationUser.getId());
Collections.sort(notificationList);
return notificationList;
```

Other option, you can update your `SQL` query to return data in reverse order by using

```
ORDER BY <column_name> DESC;
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is tricky: The list you get is only ad hoc. It list the entities in the order that the database found the records in the database which *usually* is the order in which you stored it but that can change at any time depending on the execution plan of your query. Whatever order you are receiving today may be different tomorrow.

If you need the result in a specific order you have to specify it in your JPQL query. So it would become `SELECT u FROM User WHERE u.id=? ORDER BY u.id DESC`.